# Outlook automatically set shared mailbox address for sending new mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, shared-mailbox

I'm unable to create a new e-mail when selecting the Inbox folder on a shared mailbox.

Example: admin@example.org has full access on mailbox user@example.org.
If I reply an e-mail, it will choose user@example.org automatically.
However if I create a new e-mail it will always choose admin@example.org as that's my default account.

Is it possible in Outlook to set the correct user for creating a new e-mail when selecting something (like Inbox or Sent Items) in the delegated mailbox?

The issue is that I have to manually select the "From" property each time I send a fresh e-mail.

Extra information: 1 user manages multiple other mailboxes, so setting just 1 as default will not resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

See the article
[Change the account used to send email messages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-account-used-to-send-email-messages-2bdd8d4f-e30f-4ec8-88a0-406ce7b23cc5):

> **Change your default email account**
>
> You can change your default email account using the following steps.
>
> - Select **File > Account Settings > Account Settings**.
> - From the list of accounts on the **Email** tab, select the account you want to use as the default account.
> - Select **Set as Default > Close**.

Comment: This only works for setting all accounts as default. There's like 8 mailboxes being managed from this perspective. So this is not fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, only one default "From" address can be set in Outlook. I'm afraid that your requirement cannot be realized.

Answer (score 0):

in case this is still an issue for someone:

You need to disable automapping for the shared mailbox and then add the mailbox as an additional mailbox to Outlook but use the users own credentials to connect to it

To disable automapping use PS - automapping is enabled by default:

Remove current mailbox permissin to the shared mailbox for that user: Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity <*shared mailbox> -User '' -AccessRight FullAccess

Re-add it with automapping disabled: Add-MailboxPermission -Identity <*shared mailbox> -User ' -AccessRight FullAccess -InheritanceType All -Automapping $false

To fix the send items going in the wrong mailbox send items folder:

on users pc add the following reg key needs to be added: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook\Preferences DWORD 32 > DelegateSentItemsStyle value = 1

On Exchange server MessageCopyForSentAsEnabled needs to be set to false

To check the current status & change it in PS: get-Mailbox <*shared mailbox> | select MessageCopyForSentAsEnabled

If it is enabled you need to disable it Set-Mailbox <*shared mailbox> -MessageCopyForSentAsEnabled $false